# Windows Domain URL

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, internal-dns, windows-server-2019

Our laptops are connected to a windows server 2019 with the domain name company.int 
Everything works find and when I ping company.int it points to the windows server. The server is also responsible for internal DNS. All machines are using this server's ip as primary DNS and routers IP as secondary. 
The problem is that we also want to have an intranet located at company.int. This will be a Drupal website hosted in our DMZ (not on the same segment with the DC and machines).

How  can I have it so that when users visit company.int from the browser they are redirected to the website and not the DC server? I tried to create an A record on the Windows Server www pointing to the IP of Drupal, problem is that Drupal is configured to be hosted on http://company.int and therefor when you call www it automatically redirects to company.int.

We are trying to avoid the situation of re-configuring the DC with a different name since this might cause some unexpected situations. 
Any help is more than welcomed.

Comment: You would need to install IIS or some other program on the DC to redirect the http/https traffic to the correct location.  This is inadvisable; Drupal should be reconfigured (as noted by joeqwerty below).

Answer (score 5):

If it were me, I'd reconfigure Drupal to be hosted on www.company.int.